# Opening QtApplication from python process that is forked from QtThread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a server-client architecture. The server is a `QtApplication` and contains a `QThread`.

I am trying to open a new client process using python's built in `multiprocessing`, from the QThread, and from that new proccess, open a new `QtApplication` . Such that the server and the client are both running QtApplications

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

> WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.

The QApplication is being created in the main thread of the new processes, so I am not sure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

**A Qoute from Kovid Goyal:**

> Don't use multiprocessing. multiprocessing is not thread safe, on unix
>   it uses fork() without exec() which means that it inherits
>   *everything*  from the parent process including locks (which are in an invalid state  in the child process), file handles, global objects
>   like QApplication  and so on. Just as an illustration of the problems
>   multiprocessing can  cause, if you use it with the standard library
>   logging module you can  have your worker processes crash, since the
>   logging module uses locks.
>
> After all, what do you expect to happen to QApplication on fork()? 
>   There's no way for fork() to have the QApplication object magically 
>   re-initialize itself.
>
> Using multiprocessing *will* bite you in the rear on any project of 
>   moderate complexity. Heck it bit me on the rear even while
>   implementing  a muti-core replacment for grep. Instead use subprocess
>   to launch a  worker process, feed it a module name, functions and
>   arguments on stdin  using cPickle or json and then have it run the
>   task.

See: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/multiprocessing-with-QApplication-td4977972.html